# Postgres - decode unicode UTF-16 characters in URL

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to decode URLs containing UTF-16 unicode characters in order to replace the unicode by the corresponding symbol (in Postgres)

Ex : https://example.com/xyz/ps5 playstation 5?sortu003dnewest  ->  https://example.com/abc/ps5 playstation 5?sort=newest

Basically, replacing u003d by & in this example by calling the replace function.

But considering the number of unicodes, I was wondering if there is another function or a better way to handle all of the possibilities.

Thank you for any potential hints.

Comment: That isn't utf-16 though is it? It's an escape code, but not a standard URL percent encoding. I'm no expert but I don't think it's a valid International Resource Indicator either. Where did it come from and do you need it to be a valid URL?